# Things to Consider in Making an "Account Controller" in ASP.NET MVC 2

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, security

I'm making a site using VS 2010 using the Empty ASP.NET MVC 2 template and I'm going to make my own AccountController for the Log-in/Security.

Having the DB ready and taking into account that I need to make the Model for the user account what are the major techniques or methodologies that I should consider in making my AccountController?

Comment: <Insert lecture on rolling your own authentication system here>. DotNetOpenAuth has made my life a lot better.

Answer (score 1):

There aren't specific things that you should consider when making an account controller that are different than things to consider when making any other controller.

- design view models
- controller actions such as 2 Login actions (one for GET and one for POST) for respectively showing the login form and handling the form submission.
- if you want to handle things like forgotten password, change password, etc... those could be action to this controller as well.
- when the login is successful and you are using a returnurl to redirect back to where the user initially was make sure you check that this url belongs to your domain to avoid spoofing.
- make sure that the controller action which receives the username and password is accessible only with HTTPS.
- if you are using [forms authentication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647070.aspx) you may take a look at the [following article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648341.aspx) for configuring the cookie for increased security.

Comment: Thanks for you input. I posted this question just to be sure I'm not missing anything important with making a controller for the site log-in.